# Strange characters in all man pages

Tags: 16.04

Whenever I look up a command in the man pages I get output that looks similar to this:
eg. for `man ls`

```
ls [OPTION0m]... [FILE0m]...
```

This weird character displays over/on certain words in the man page. I can still read what the text is supposed to say but it is very annoying to read around this weird character thing. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Those look like esc sequences, what is your TERM variable set to? echo $TERM

Comment: @ubfan1 my $TERM is: xterm-256color